# What is the purpose of UTF-8 hex 00 (U+0000) to hex 1f (U+001f)?

Tags: networking, websocket, utf-8, hex

How and where are they used? What are they for in the context of networking, specifically, websockets?

Comment: They are ASCII code. Unicode should be compatible with ASCII, so we had them. -- Two are used for new lines. -- Websockets doesn't need to use all unicode cope points (and some code points hsould not be used, in any case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters x00-x1F are [*"C0 control codes"*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes). A few of them are generally used and understood, such as the tab character or the line separator characters, but most of them are rarely used. They are sometimes used in special contexts, for example in hardware or in specific communication protocols.

In the context of websockets, the control codes do not have any special meaning, with perhaps the exception of the carriage return CR x0D and line feed x0A characters. These characters are used to terminate HTTP protocol headers in the initial websocket handshake.